# What does it mean by 3D Compatible

Tags: projector, home-theater

I have a `Marquee Digital Labs Home Theater MD-1000LED TV Projector 1080 MP` 3D-Projector I got on [EBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Marquee-Digital-Labs-Home-Theater-MD-1000LED-TV-Projector-1080-MP-60-Screen-/111047299162?pt=US_Video_Projectors&hash=item19daef505a)

Can someone tell me what does it mean by 3D Compatible it also came with 3D Glasses but I don't if it can play 3D Movies or not.

I also have this [Sony Home Theater with Blu Rayer](http://store.sony.com/p/BDV-E370/en/p/BDVE370) where from their APP store I can play 3D Trailers and also can rent 3D movies but when I try to play trailer I only get sound and video it says "Invalid for" which I think means Invalid Format.

Thanks

Comment: It means that if you rent or buy a movie which does support 3D technology than you will be able to watch the movie on your Projector in 3D, but you must wear the glasses.

Comment: I tried that, my blu ray lets me rents movie and also lets me play Trailer before renting it, it doesn't even play the 3D trailer only sound, video it says Invalid format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you should be able to view 3D movies if you plug a bluray player or any other device capable of 3D, such as this one:

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Panasonic+-+3D+Blu-ray+Disc+Player/5060175.p?id=1218604364022&skuId=5060175&st=3d%20bluray&cp=1&lp=1

You would have to check if your specific Sony Bluray is capable of playing 3D content. Just because you can get such content from the app might not necessarily mean you can play said content.

Comment: I have this http://store.sony.com/p/BDV-E370/en/p/BDVE370  home theater which has can play 3D movies but I dont have 3D TV so it never play any 3D trailer or anything but now I have projector above but it still doesn't player 3D trailer from Sony BluRay player

Comment: Have you tried a 3D bluray disk? Might be worth renting one to see if you get the same result.

Comment: True, I'll do that, but if my projector says it can play and my blu ray says it can play it still doesn't play I am confused.

Comment: Understandable. It could also be an incompatibility between the player and the projector, hard to tell. Also if you bought it from eBay it may be an issue with the projector, considering it seems you are getting a $6000 projector for $500.

Comment: Very true, I have contacted Sony, hopefully they can find solution for me, but I must say this project plays very high def non 3d movies. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The other thing you may want to check is the cable between your player and projector (or player->receiver->projector if that is how you are set up). [There are 5 types of HDMI cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Cables), you need to use `High Speed` or `High Speed with Ethernet` (you likely don't need Ethernet) to use 3D. Grab a [cheep](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10240#1024008) `High Speed` cable and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for your input I'll try that too.